# Assigning values to variables in a loop

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, variable

In the full code pasted below I'd like to avoid the if statement within the if statement.
I'd like to assign the values stored in @rows into the @Voucher1 and @Voucher2 variables using the incrementor i.

Ie. replacing this part:

```
 if @i == 1 THEN
  set @Voucher1 = field(@row,"Voucher")
 else
  set @Voucher2 = field(@row,"Voucher")
 endif
```

with something like this:

```
 set @Voucher[1] = field(@row,"Voucher")
```

If possible, how would I do that?
Thank you!

```
<script language="ampscript" runat="server">
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @email, @i, @Voucher1, @Voucher2
set @email = AttributeValue("Email") /* value from attribute or DE column in send context */
set @rows = LookupRows("InternorgaVouchers","RealEmailAddress", @email)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
if @rowCount > 0 then
 for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
 set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
 if @i == 1 THEN
  set @Voucher1 = field(@row,"Voucher")
 else
  set @Voucher2 = field(@row,"Voucher")
 endif
 next @i
else
 RaiseError('No vouchers found', false)
endif
</script>
```

FYI:
As I know the setup I'm working with will never return more than 2 values, this is my temporary solution that is actually working. But it is clumsy and not flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to build it out as a string and then do a TreatAsContent. Something like below:

```ampscript
%%[
set @email = AttributeValue("Email") /* value from attribute or DE column in send context */
set @rows = LookupRows("InternorgaVouchers","RealEmailAddress", @email)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
if @rowCount > 0 then
 for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
   set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
   set @tempVar = TreatAsContent(CONCAT("%","%[ SET @Voucher",@i," = field(@row,'Voucher')]%","%"))
 next @i
else
 RaiseError('No vouchers found', false)
endif
]%%
```

Basically what this does is Use the CONCAT variable to build out the string (assuming @i = 2): `%%[ SET @Voucher2 = field(@row,'Voucher')]%%`

This, by itself, will not get you much despite being valid AMPscript. This is due to the order or processing, it will not parse it to validate if its AMPscript for processing or not as the function will output it as a string.

So to change that to have it processed - you need to wrap it inside of a TreatAsContent to let the system know it needs to run this as if it were a content block.

You may notice I have this all set on a variable, which is just for clean syntax. The variable and value returned in that variable are pretty meaningless. The running of that concat script to dynamically set the variables is the important part.